# How to temporarily switch profiles for AWS CLI?

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, command-line, aws-cli

Updated answer (7/10/2021): For AWS CLI v1, do this:

```sh
export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user2
```

For AWS CLI v2, the following will work:

```sh
export AWS_PROFILE=user2
```

The full question is below for context:

---

(1.) After successfully configuring a second profile for the AWS CLI, I unsuccessfully tried to set the profile to user2 in my bash session with the following command:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=user2
```

... per the advice here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html

(2.) The following command works:

```sh
aws s3 ls --profile user2
```

So I know that the AWS CLI and the user2 profile are both working on my computer.

(3.) However, when I subsequently (that is, after entering "export AWS_PROFILE=user2") try something like:

```sh
aws s3 ls
```

... AWS's response assumes that I want to query it as the default user (NOT user2)

(4.) So the only way I can use the user2 profile from the command line is by continuing to append "--profile user2" to every single command, which is tedious.

(5.)

```sh
echo $AWS_PROFILE
```

yields:

```sh
>> user2
```

, as expected.

Any idea what's going on here? I'm sure I'm making some dumb mistake somewhere.

Comment: What you are looking for is the expected behavior. Refer this AWS document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence. Can you confirm that you are setting the environment variables in the same session as where you are running the aws command?

Comment: What do you get from `AWS_PROFILE=user2 aws s3 ls`? Does *that* use `user2` successfully?

Comment: which version of aws-cli are you using?

Comment: This will also help you understand what awscli is doing wrt credentials: aws s3 ls --debug | grep botocore.session

Comment: Krishna, I definitely am setting the AWS_PROFILE variable in the same session as the one that I am running the command in. The website you linked to is not helpful to me.

Comment: Grisha, the command you suggested does not use user2 successfully.

Comment: jarmod, I ran that command and it did not illuminate the nature of the problem for me.

Comment: What Grisha said is right. If you run that command, it should definitely be using user2 profile.

Comment: Krishna. Okay, well I just tried it again and it did not...

Comment: can you try `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user2` ?

Comment: @kintuparantu That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 134, accepted):

For AWS CLI v1, the cleanest solution is:

```sh
export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user2
```

Afterward, commands like:

```
aws s3 ls
```

... are handled from the appropriate account.

For AWS CLI v2, the following will work:

```sh
export AWS_PROFILE=user2
```

Comment: Per Diego's comment below, this variable name has been renamed to `AWS_PROFILE`.  [More here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#envvars-list).

Comment: @emilebaizel actually "export AWS_PROFILE=[profile_name]" has never worked for me or for many others, hence the popularity of this question.

Comment: does this still fail for you with the latest AWS CLI?

Comment: @emilebaizel "export AWS_PROFILE=user2" does work in AWS CLI v2

Comment: For anyone interested here is a [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html#:~:text=output%3Dtext-,Using%20named%20profiles,-To%20use%20a) to official AWS documentation on this.

Comment: This was not working for me after I setup `~/.aws/credentials` and added a user2 profile. This was because I had set environment variables, e.g. `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` which were taking precedence. I removed those and now it's working.

Answer (score 35):

The accepted answer assumes you are using a Linux or Mac terminal. I added commands for Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

### Windows

#### CMD

`set AWS_PROFILE=profile_name`

#### Powershell

`$env:AWS_PROFILE = 'profile_name'`

### Linux or Mac

`export AWS_PROFILE=profile_name`

These will set your aws profile that you will use every time you execute an aws command. But if you just want to switch profile temporarily for one aws command.

`aws [command] [sub-command] --profile [profile-name]`

Comment: The windows answer here is for cmd. For powershell it is `$env:AWS_PROFILE = 'profile_name'`

Comment: This doesn't work. If I run aws configure list, I get 

access_key     ****************BMSB shared-credentials-file    
secret_key     ****************JStS shared-credentials-file 

then if I run

set AWS_PROFILE=scoop_production

and re-run aws configure list I get the same details, which aren't the correct details for scoop_production.

Answer (score 10):

You can see how it works doing this

```
$ export AWS_PROFILE=myprofile
$ aws s3 ls --debug 2>&1 | grep profile
2018-04-08 19:19:17,990 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from environment with value 'myprofile'.
```

I doubt this works differently for you.

You can also verify that

```
$ AWS_PROFILE=myprofile aws s3 ls --debug 2>&1 | grep profile
```

and

```
$ aws s3 ls --profile myprofile --debug 2>&1 | grep profile
```

all give the same result.

Comment: These commands do NOT yield the same result for me.

The first two do not produce any output. The final one produces the following output: "2018-04-08 23:11:33,683 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['s3', 'ls', '--profile', 'myprofile', '--debug']
2018-04-08 23:11:33,683 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Skipping environment variable credential check because profile name was explicitly set.

Comment: @JamesShapiro remove `| grep profile` from the first commands and see what's there

Answer (score 7):

create or edit this file:

```
% vim ~/.aws/credentials
```

list as many key pairs as you like:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

[user1]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
```

include `--profile user1` to select a profile & do what you like:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --profile user1
# any aws cli command now using user1 pair of keys
```

.... OR ....

set a local variable to select the pair of keys you want to use:

```
% export AWS_PROFILE=user1
```

then do what you like:

```
aws s3api list-buckets  # any aws cli command now using user1 pair of keys
```

more details:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

Comment: That option is listed as suboptimal in the original problem description. It's not a good one, because it involves appending "--profile [user]" to every single CLI command that you run.

Comment: I would suggest deleting, there is nothing in your answer that is not explicitly stated in the answers above.

Answer (score 2):

AWS cli has 3 level of ways it will read variables

- environment variables of key_id / key_secret
- profile via cred/config (normally in ~/.aws/cre...)
- manual value provided inline

> see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#credentials

one way will be overwritten by another. based on OP, it might be that although DEFAULT_PROFILE is set as userX, the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and/or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment variables is set to something else.

You can do an alias to a shell function that load credentials to the current environment thru the use of

```
"export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXX;"... and more
```

or to be safer load via a secrets manager

```
"export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws configure get aws_access_key_id --profile XXXX)"... and more
```

Export all access key/secrets etc and then check that the right credentials are loaded in memory thru

```
aws configure list
```

finally.. do a reset of the the variable to "default" .. as a good habit to ensure you do what you need as the AWS role; especially when using multiple profiles. hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
aws --version
```

```
aws-cli/2.1.2 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.4.0-53-generic exe/x86_64.linuxmint.20
```

I add aliases to my *.bashrc* if I have a lot of named profiles.

for example:

```bash
alias harry-tuttle='export AWS_PROFILE=harry-tuttle'
```

Then switching profiles becomes one command with less typing.

To see all your profiles:

```bash
aws configure list-profiles
```

Answer (score 2):

[You could add the `profile` flag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html)

```
aws s3 ls --profile marketingadmin
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to specify what's the case for windows users -

1. Use set for setting environment variable for the current terminal session.

   ```
   set AWS_PROFILE=some_profile_name
   ```
2. Use setx for setting environment variable that stays even if the terminal is closed.

   ```
   setx AWS_PROFILE=some_profile_name
   ```

One thing to keep in mind is that while using setx, the environment variable gets set in the new terminal session. The existing session will not yield the set environment variable value.

Answer (score 1):

For **windows** use

```sh
set AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user2
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! Please read [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Try to include what your answer does better and/or differently compared to the already accepted one!