# How to switch default profile in aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws

For testing purpose, I am running on a docker container.

```
sudo docker run --entrypoint "/bin/bash" --rm -it amazon/aws-cli:latest
```

I configured default profile with my admin account.

Then, configured another profile with sts role linked.

```
bash-4.2# cat ~/.aws/config
[default]
region = us-west-2
[profile testsubaccount]
source_profile = default
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_NUMBER>:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole
region = us-west-2
```

Now, see the output of below command.

```
bash-4.2# aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "********",
    "Account": "*******",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::********:user/*******"
}
bash-4.2# aws sts get-caller-identity --profile testawsaccount

The config profile (testawsaccount) could not be found
bash-4.2# aws sts get-caller-identity --profile testsubaccount
{
    "UserId": "*********************",
    "Account": "********",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::********:assumed-role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole/botocore-session-1653571765"
}
```

If you observe, with --profile option it is showing the second profile and without any parameter, it is showing default account.

I want to run my aws cli commands and the terraform files also to use the second profile as default so that I don't need to change all my templates and commands.

When I checked it is mentioned that setting

```
export AWS_PROFILE=testsubaccount

export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=testsubaccount
```

should switch the default profile.

But not working.

Tried with and without export keyword.

Reference links:
[How do I set the name of the default profile in AWS CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012460/how-do-i-set-the-name-of-the-default-profile-in-aws-cli)
[How to temporarily switch profiles for AWS CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716583/how-to-temporarily-switch-profiles-for-aws-cli)

Comment: What specifically is not working? What happens when you run `AWS_PROFILE=testsubaccount aws sts get-caller-identity` (all on the same line in your shell)?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are working on unix machine.

1. Go to your aws configurations folder, which is available at `~/.aws/`.
2. Open the `credentials` file whose content will be something like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = *****
aws_secret_access_key = **************

[another-profile]
aws_access_key_id = *************
aws_secret_access_key = ***********
```

3. In *[default]*, just configure the keys that you want to set as your default config for aws-cli and you are good to go.

> Note: You can copy the items from any other AWS profile into your *[default]*. If you want this config to be temporary, then make sure to backup your *[default]* setup backed up into another profile like *[old-default]* which will make it easier to switch back later.